# Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed cannot remove console error after using the input check box

Tags: asp.net-core, angular6, .net-core-2.2

I'm trying to bind the data from api which is written in .net core with angular api using ng for i getting the value properly but when i use the check input field my console is full on unstoppable errors

I have tried many examples from stackoverflow non them worked for me

```
export class UsermanagementComponent {
userDetailsList: any = [];
public userList: any= [];
departmentuser: any = {};
public searchTxt:any;
isActive: boolean = false;
checkuserstatus: boolean;


 constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient, private 
 toastr: ToastrService, private appComponent: AppComponent) {
 this.userList
}
private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();
ngOnInit() {
this.appComponent.startSpinner();
this.getuser();
;   
}



edituser(userList: any) {
localStorage.setItem("userList", JSON.stringify(userList));
console.log(userList);
this.router.navigate(["/landingpage/edituser"], userList);
}
lockUnlockUser(userList: any) {
console.log(userList);
this.http.post(environment.apiUrl + "Account/LockUserAccount", userList, 
{
}).subscribe(data => {
  this.appComponent.stopSpinner();
  this.router.navigate(["/landingpage/usermanagement"]);     
  this.userList = data;
  this.checkuserstatus = this.userList.lockoutEnabled;
  console.log(this.checkuserstatus);
  if (this.checkuserstatus == true) {
   let toast = this.toastr.success(MessageVariable.UserLocked);
    alert(toast);
  } else if (this.checkuserstatus == false) {
    let toast = this.toastr.info(MessageVariable.UserUnLocked);
    alert(toast);
  }
  }, (err) => {
    this.toastr.error(MessageVariable.ErrorMsg);
  });
  }


  getuser() {
  this.appComponent.startSpinner();
  var userId = localStorage.getItem('userid');
  console.log(userId);
  this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + "Account/GetUser", {
  }).subscribe(data =>  {
  this.appComponent.stopSpinner();
  this.userList = data;
  console.log(this.userList);

  }, (err) => {
  this.toastr.error(MessageVariable.ErrorMsg);
  });
}
```

}

```
UsermanagementComponent.html:22 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
at
```

Comment: the error shows something wrong in your view (.html file) , please post your html file as well.

Comment: Solved Thank you